# Xamarin macOs CreateBookmarkData WithSecurityScope results in The file couldn’t be opened

Tags: macos, xamarin

This code used to work, but after installing Visual Studio for Mac 2022 it doesn't work anymore:

```
                var dlg = NSOpenPanel.OpenPanel;
                dlg.AllowsMultipleSelection = false;
                dlg.CanChooseFiles = false;
                dlg.CanChooseDirectories = true;

                if (dlg.RunModal() == 1)
                {
                    if (dlg.Url != null)
                    {
                        NSError error = new NSError();
                        string[] resourceValues = {  };
                        var data = dlg.Url.CreateBookmarkData(NSUrlBookmarkCreationOptions.WithSecurityScope, resourceValues, null, out error);
                        var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
                        userDefaults.SetValueForKey(data, new NSString("MBVFolderBookmark"));

                    }
                }
```

The error parameter is {The file couldn’t be opened.}
The same error show with files or folders.

Other options of NSUrlBookmarkCreationOptions still works.

What can it be?

Comment: which line cause the error?

Comment: the line: var data = dlg.Url.CreateBookmarkData throws the error.

Comment: Does it work if you change NSUrlBookmarkCreationOptions to other value?

Comment: Yes it do work with other options. I mentioned that 'Other options of NSUrlBookmarkCreationOptions still works.'

Comment: if it used to work, it could be something with the vs, try to post a feedback here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that my certificate (developer ID) was expired.
Creating a new one did solve this problem...